# What does a colon followed by two column names after a relationship do when eager loading?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatables, eager-loading

When looking for a fix for an issue I had dealing with **Datatables**, I found this interesting syntax but I cannot find anything on the Laravel documentation to help me understand what's going on but I'd like to learn its useability.

This is the code snippet:

```
return $model->select('sessions.*')
        ->with('employee:id,name');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s mentioned in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

> You may not always need every column from the relationships you are retrieving. For this reason, Eloquent allows you to specify which columns of the relationship you would like to retrieve:
>
> ```php
> $books = Book::with('author:id,name')->get();
> ```

Comment: This will come in handy. Thank you, Martin!